# Initializing Raphael with an svg element

Tags: javascript, html, svg, raphael

I have already an SVG element on my HTML page. How can I initialize Raphael with it so that it wont create a new SVG, but use the one I provide.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Raph will allow you to do this. I think you will need to give it a div or container that Raph will place the svg/vml place inside. I don't think you can give it an existing element to use (as svg).

I suspect this is because Raphael does not only create SVG, but possibly VML if its one of the very old browser versions. If you definitely need SVG and want to only use existing elements, you may want to look at Snap.svg, which is Raphaels younger sister (and shares a lot of the same codebase), or another like SVG.js.

Comment: Thanks, I just want SVG. I just started my work, so wont be any problem switching to Snap.svg.